# Cannot close nested showModal polyfill in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Trying to get IE11 specific app to run in Chrome.
Was using the polyfill (github.com/niutech/showModalDialog) successfully until I ran in to the below scenario.

I load ASPX page 1 with a button to load ASPX page 2 via showModal.
(note: jquery.min.js is v1.4.2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm1</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            window.spawn = window.spawn || function (gen) {
                function continuer(verb, arg) {
                    var result;
                    try {
                        result = generator[verb](arg);
                    } catch (err) {
                        return Promise.reject(err);
                    }
                    if (result.done) {
                        return result.value;
                    } else {
                        return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
                    }
                }
                var generator = gen();
                var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, 'next');
                var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, 'throw');
                return onFulfilled();
            };
            window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function (url, arg, opt) {
                url = url || '';                                        // URL of a dialog
                arg = arg || null;                                      // arguments to a dialog
                //opt = opt || "dialogWidth:410px; dialogHeight:420px;dialogTop:" + top + "px;dialogLeft:" + left + "px";    //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
                var caller = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
                var dialog = parent.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
                dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
                dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
                parent.document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
                parent.document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    dialog.close();
                });
                dialog.showModal();
                //if using yield or async/await
                if (caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0 || caller.indexOf('await') >= 0) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                            var returnValue = parent.document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                            parent.document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                            resolve(returnValue);
                        });
                    });
                }
                //if using eval
                var isNext = false;
                var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function (stmt) {
                    if (isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
                        return isNext = true;
                    return false;
                });
                dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                    var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                    parent.document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                    nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
                    eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
                });
                throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
            };
        })();

        /*******************************************************************************
        * Purpose:  Opens a popup 
        * ********************************************************************************/
        async function OpenSiteMinder() {
            var title = "Refresh List";
            var details = "Authorizing";
            var settingsString = new String();

            // Fixes dual-screen position on most browsers
            var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
            var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
            var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
            var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;

            var left = ((width / 2) - (410 / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
            var top = ((height / 2) - (420 / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

            settingsString = "WebForm2.aspx";

            var returns = await window.showModalDialog(settingsString, window, "edge:sunken;help:no;unadorned:yes;center:yes;status:no;dialogWidth:410px; dialogHeight:420px;dialogTop:" + top + "px;dialogLeft:" + left + "px'");

        }//end of function OpenSiteMinder(sourceID, path)   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form2" method="post" runat="server">
        <input class="button" id="btnOK" onclick="javascript:OpenSiteMinder(); return false;" type="submit" value="OpenWebForm2" runat="server" />
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnWebForm1" name="hdnWebForm1" value="No"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX page 2 opens ASPX page 3 via showModal

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm2</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function () {
            window.spawn = window.spawn || function (gen) {
                function continuer(verb, arg) {
                    var result;
                    try {
                        result = generator[verb](arg);
                    } catch (err) {
                        return Promise.reject(err);
                    }
                    if (result.done) {
                        return result.value;
                    } else {
                        return Promise.resolve(result.value).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
                    }
                }
                var generator = gen();
                var onFulfilled = continuer.bind(continuer, 'next');
                var onRejected = continuer.bind(continuer, 'throw');
                return onFulfilled();
            };
            window.showModalDialog = window.showModalDialog || function (url, arg, opt) {
                url = url || '';                                        // URL of a dialog
                arg = arg || null;                                      // arguments to a dialog
                //opt = opt || "dialogWidth:410px; dialogHeight:420px;dialogTop:" + top + "px;dialogLeft:" + left + "px";    //options: dialogTop;dialogLeft;dialogWidth;dialogHeight or CSS styles
                var caller = arguments.callee.caller.toString();
                var dialog = parent.document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('dialog'));
                dialog.setAttribute('style', opt.replace(/dialog/gi, ''));
                dialog.innerHTML = '<a href="#" id="dialog-close" style="position: absolute; top: 0; right: 5px; font-size: 20px; color: #000; text-decoration: none; outline: none;">&times;</a><iframe id="dialog-body" src="' + url + '" style="border: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>';
                parent.document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.dialogArguments = arg;
                parent.document.getElementById('dialog-close').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    dialog.close();
                });
                dialog.showModal();
                //if using yield or async/await
                if (caller.indexOf('yield') >= 0 || caller.indexOf('await') >= 0) {
                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                            var returnValue = parent.document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                            parent.document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                            resolve(returnValue);
                        });
                    });
                }
                //if using eval
                var isNext = false;
                var nextStmts = caller.split('\n').filter(function (stmt) {
                    if (isNext || stmt.indexOf('showModalDialog(') >= 0)
                        return isNext = true;
                    return false;
                });
                dialog.addEventListener('close', function () {
                    var returnValue = document.getElementById('dialog-body').contentWindow.returnValue;
                    parent.document.body.removeChild(dialog);
                    nextStmts[0] = nextStmts[0].replace(/(window\.)?showModalDialog\(.*\)/g, JSON.stringify(returnValue));
                    eval('{\n' + nextStmts.join('\n'));
                });
                throw 'Execution stopped until showModalDialog is closed';
            };
        })();

        /*******************************************************************************
        * Purpose:  Opens a popup 
        * ********************************************************************************/
        async function OpenSiteMinder() {
            var title = "Refresh List";
            var details = "Authorizing";
            var settingsString = new String();
            // Fixes dual-screen position on most browsers
            var dualScreenLeft = window.screenLeft != undefined ? window.screenLeft : screen.left;
            var dualScreenTop = window.screenTop != undefined ? window.screenTop : screen.top;
            var width = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width;
            var height = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height;
            var left = ((width / 2) - (410 / 2)) + dualScreenLeft;
            var top = ((height / 2) - (420 / 2)) + dualScreenTop;

            settingsString = "WebForm3.aspx";

            var returns = await window.showModalDialog(settingsString, window, "edge:sunken;help:no;unadorned:yes;center:yes;status:no;dialogWidth:410px; dialogHeight:420px;dialogTop:" + top + "px;dialogLeft:" + left + "px'");
        }//end of function OpenSiteMinder(sourceID, path)
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" method="post"  runat="server">
        <div>
            <p><span><b>WebForm2</b></span></p>
            <span class="body11RED" id="ctrlMessage" runat="server"><b></b></span>
            <p class="body">WebForm2 stuff:</p>
            <p class="body">
                <input class="button" id="btnOK" onclick="javascript:OpenSiteMinder(); return false;" type="submit" value="Open WebForm3" runat="server"/>
            </p>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnWebForm2" name="hdnWebForm4" value="No"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ASPX Page 3 opens ASPX page 4 inside of a frame.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm3</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p><span><b>WebForm3 opens WebForm4 inside frame</b></span></p>
            <iframe id="iFrameProcessTransaction" runat="server" src="Webform4.aspx" style="height:240px; width:330px"></iframe>
        </div>
         <input type="hidden" runat="server" id="hdnWebForm3" name="hdnWebForm3" value="No"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want ASPX Page 4 Yes button to return to ASPX page 2. *parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close()* fails and *parent.parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close()* works but takes me to WebForm1.  How do I get it to return to ASPX page 2? (note: 3rd party requirements specify ASPX4 be opened in a frame) I can not close the modal showing aspx3 with the contents of aspx4 spawned from aspx2.  Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm4</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" > 
            function PassConfirmation(authenticated) {
                var valid = "Yes";
                var paramsObject = new Object();
                
                paramsObject.authenticated = valid;
                window.returnValue = paramsObject;

                //parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();
                //window.parent.parent.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();  //does not work
                //window.parent.frames[0].document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close(); 
                parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();

                //window.close();
                //return false;
            }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p><span><b>WebForm4: I want clicking Yes to take me back to WebForm2's return of it's showModal</b></span></p>
            <br />
            <button id="btnYes" runat="server" onclick="PassConfirmation('Yes'); return false;" >Yes</button>
            <button id="btnNo" onclick="PassConfirmation('No'); return false;" >No</button>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```